# Calculat ratio on Kibana using two indices

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to do something basic in SQL, but I struggle to find a way to do it with Kibana.

I want to calculate a ratio between two indices group by country over time.

My two indices:

index 1: `AppUser {creationDate, countryCode, etc...}`

index 2: `Transactions {creationDate, status, countryCode, etc...}`

I want to have a visualization in a table or pie chart of the ratio  per country.

In mind the algorithm is something like this:

```
(number of transactions per countryCode with status successful / number of accounts created per countryCode)*100
```

Please how could I achieve this?

Thank you for your help

**TIMELION**

```
.es(q='sum of transactions', index=appusertransaction, timefield=garaTransactionDate, metric='count:*')
.divide(
.es(q='sum of user accounts',index=appuser, timefield=createDate, metric='count:*' ))
```

I created this timelion expression, but no way to add filter to have only successful transactions and no way to group by country in order to get which country we have the highest ratio.